# Python selenium multithreading loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, selenium

I need suggestions for a script I’m trying to make.

Main file

```
import selenium 
import threading
import time
import config
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://google.com/"

print("Running on " + config.threads + " thread(s)")

def start():
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")
    test.send_keys("testing")
    driver.close()

tc = 0
for x in range(int(config.threads)):
    tc += 1
    t = threading.Thread(target=start)
    t.start()
```

Config file

```
threads  = "5"
```

I’m trying to make it when a driver closes, the it opens a new one. So basically infinitely opens drivers. Only to the maximum 5 threads though. Any help is appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could simply add a `while True` loop inside the `start()` function. You might or might not want to handle exceptions as well, depending on your goals.

Comment: Thomas is right, however, I would be careful with only starting the threads .... if a timeout is not present, it might get stuck somewhere and die ... also as Thomas mentioned, if an exception occurs and you do not handle it, you might lose the thread completely (even to somekinda minor detail ... especially since you are using `time.sleep(5)` ... check out this answer where I have a default time after which the thread gets killed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976689/selenium-threads-how-to-run-multi-threaded-browser-with-proxy-python/53976901#53976901

Comment: FYI you won't get real concurrency with selenium. Switch to pyppeteer for that.