# how to add a proxy to each thread

Tags: python, proxy, pool

Please tell me how to add a proxy to each thread, I've been racking my head for a whole hour I can't understand.The code for cheating views on the video, now the code works, in the admin panel you can see that the vidos is viewing from one ip, and views are not added, but you need to do 20k views per day

```
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

from loguru import logger

if not os.path.exists('./chromedriver.exe'):
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install(True)


def run_driver(args: list[str, int]):
    try:
        url = args[0]
        num = args[1]

        chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
            "excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        driver = Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    
        driver.get(url)
        driver.set_window_size(1280, 720)
        time.sleep(120)
        logger.debug(f'{num} - Закончил! ')
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_url = ('https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/610ec7ba16a13f1ef5409629/scenka-vygnali-iz- 
    podezda-na-moroz-no-nashlis-dobrye-liudi-i-vot-chto-oni-sdelali-6116ec3d6eab3f04de64e704')

    process_count = 50
    views_count = 50000

    # run_driver([main_url, 0])

    args = [(main_url, i + 1) for i in range(views_count)]
    with Pool(process_count) as pool:
        pool.map(run_driver, args)
```

Comment: You can have a function to choose a "random" proxy and call that function for each run. That said, I'm not sure what you're doing is quite ethical...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add proxy to a driver, you have to use `--proxy-server` argument. Here is how I am doing it :)

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % str(proxy))
```

3 years ago, I have answered a simmilar question with my spagetti and there is a few more ppl that have answered at a same time. You can check that answer as well to see whether it will help you with something if you need -> [Selenium Threads: how to run multi-threaded browser with proxy ( python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976689/selenium-threads-how-to-run-multi-threaded-browser-with-proxy-python/53976901#53976901)